# What does "besänftigt" mean?

Tags: german-to-english, swiss-german

besänftigt translates to "mollified", which is a word seldom used in English. What does this word besänftigt really mean

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how this isn't answerable with a dictionary, see for example [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bes%C3%A4nftigen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word ''besänftigen'' ("be-sänftigen") comes from "sanft". "sanft" translates to "gentle" and "besänftigen" is "to make something/someone gentle (as contrary to i.e. furious)".

This is why you can "besänftigen" only persons and things with the potential to become furious and to be appeased/mollified again. Hunger and thirst (as mentioned by @tofro) are such things ("Den Hunger besänftigen" does mean "to eat", but with the connotation of "make the hunger more bearable" rather than "eat as much as you can"). Otherwise the word is mostly used in respect to persons.

Comment: thanks. an explanation of the deep connotation behind it was what was looking for

Answer (score 3):

It has basically the same meaning as *to appease* - With the difference that you can appease hunger or thirst, but it only works with persons (or impersonated things) in German.

Answer (score 3):

It means to calm so, to appease, to soothe, to mollify etc. See e.g. [dict.leo](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/bes%C3%A4nftigen) or [usage examples in dwds](https://www.dwds.de/wb/bes%C3%A4nftigen).

> Der Bürgermeister besänftigte die erregten Gemüter indem er erklärte, dass niemand die Absicht habe, eine Mauer zu bauen.
> (the mayor calmed the agitated crowd by declaring that no-one intends to build a wall)

> Mit dem Opfer besänftigten die Vorfahren die Götter und baten um reiche Ernte
> (With the sacrifice the ancients appeased the gods and begged for plentyful harvest)